# Basic expectation calculation logic

Tags: probability, expectation

Consider a random permutation $\sigma_{n}$ of $n$ distinct numbers from $1$ to $n$. Let $X_{n,k}$ denote the number of increasing subsequences of length $k$ over the random permutation $\sigma_{n}$. Find the expected value of $X_{n,k}$.

This problem is in the context of proving an upper bound on the expectation. This is discussed in the article [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwjdjLq6ye_HAhVVEJIKHVSgDpM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucdavis.edu%2F~romik%2Fdownload-book.php&usg=AFQjCNEr2TUepw5s9RH8HTsUN7cPSGcWkQ&sig2=JjCOS6kyz5jV0jfPsY5uVw) (Lemma 1.4, page 9). The argument and the answer is very trivial but I cannot wrap my head around that $$E(X_{n,k}) = {1 \over k!} {n \choose k}$$ This looks more like probability than expectation. Also, how does $X_{n,k}$ define over expectation? Is there a way to do the counting using some indicator variables?

Comment: Use [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity).

Comment: @joriki I agree. But I can't seem to define the corresponding indicator variables, and hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, we can use indicator functions here.

We are given a sequence $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ which is a random permutation of $1,2,\dots,n$.

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ subsequences of this sequence of length $k$. For each such subsequence $s$, let $I_s$ be the random variable which is the indicator function of that subsequence being increasing, that is:

$$
I_s =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } s \text{ not increasing} \\
  1 & \mbox{if } s \text{ increasing}
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

Now, $X_{n,k} = \displaystyle\sum_{s} I_s$, so we have:

$$
E(X_{n,k}) = \displaystyle\sum_{s} E(I_s)
$$

But the probability that a given subsequence $s$ of length $k$ is increasing is precisely $\frac{1}{k!}$, so for each $s$,

$$E(I_s) = \frac{1}{k!}$$

Thus we have:

$$E(X_{n,k}) = \displaystyle\sum_{s} E(I_s) = \frac{1}{k!} \binom{n}{k}$$

Comment: Spot on! Fills in the missing piece exactly.